Оптимизация True-False флагов
Проблема
У меня в коде, для моего удобства, используется такая конструкция для смены состояния флагов, вне зависимости от их текущего состояния:
flag *= -1

Конструкция довольно удобна, единственный минус в том, что мне не нравится как выглядит её проверка:
if flag == 1:
    print('True')

Проверка флагов True - False, конечно выглядит гораздо лучше:
if flag:
    print('True')

Однако конструкция смены состояния таких флагов заставляет мои глаза течь кровью:
if flag:
    flag = False
else:
    flag = True

Хочется собрать лучшее из этих вариантов:

Возможность проверки без условий
Возможность замены значения в одну (простую) строку

Какие варианты пришли мне в голову:
Метод 1: Класс
Самый логичный и питонячий метод — использовать класс. Минимально у меня получилось что-то такое:
class Flag():
    def __init__(self, val:bool):
        self.val = val
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.val

    def switch(self):
        if self.val:
            self.val = False
        else:
            self.val = True

И это даже работает, но проблема в том, что этот класс довольно неудобно вызывать:
Вместо flag = True надо делать flag = Flag(True). Что может выстрелить чеховским ружьём в самый неожиданный момент, когда я забуду прописать этот класс, или попробую получить значение флага от какого-то не моего метода.
Метод 2: Запихнуть флаг куда-то
Собственно, идея схожа с классом:
def switch(dct: dict):
    if dct['val']:
        dct['val'] = False
    else:
        dct['val'] = True

Минусы: вы вообще представляете как это хранить и проверять? Я представляю, и это максимально неудобно
Метод 3: вспомнить про return
def switch(val):
    if val:
        return False
    else:
        return True

my_flag = True
print(my_flag)
my_flag = switch(my_flag)
print(my_flag)

В целом, норм, но всё равно, мне не особо нравится конструкция my_flag = switch(my_flag).
Собственно вопрос:
А какой, на ваш взгляд, самый оптимальный способ хранения и переключения флагов? Скорее всего существует что-то очень простое, что может делать то, что я хочу, но прям сходу таких методов не нашлось.
Ах да, вопрос сугубо теоретический и скорее даже про "приятно глазу", но суть, в целом, надеюсь ясна

flag = not flag

И даже если бы не было not, можно было бы с флагами 0 и 1 использовать конструкцию flag = 1 - flag.

@andreymal блин, как обычно, самые базовые функции языка забываются первыми) спасибо

f = 0; f = ~f; f = -1; f = ~f; if f: ... - если требуется покрасоваться.

@StanislavVolodarskiy это рабочий метод, и действительно красивый. Но операция настолько непопулярная, что мне пришлось гуглить что происходит)


if flag:
    flag = False
else:
    flag = True


flag = not flag


Я с трудом понял эти сложности, а местами и не понял. Но попробую:
flag = True # начальное значение
flag = not flag # смена значения на противоположное
print(flag) # вывод на экран текущего значения
return flag # возврат текущего значения из функции
if flag: # если True...
if not flag: # если False...
flag = flag and my_function() # выполнение my_function() только в случае, если на входе flag = True, и формирование нового флага успешности в результате - для возможности выполнения следующего кода.


Да сложности в целом и нет. Вопрос про удобность и читабельность кода
